# Cypress: key combinations

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end, autotest

I'm trying to write the keyboard shortcut 'ctrl+F1'

I tried

```
cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}',{release:false}).trigger('keydown',{key: "F1", code:"F1", which:112});
```

But it doesn't work

What do you suggest?

Comment: ***But it doesn't work*** - what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: By the way `which` is deprecated (see [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which))

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `ctrlKey` property:

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { key: 'F1', ctrlKey: true });
```

Also you can check [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) docs.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this it will work*

```
   cy.get('[data-id="abcd"]').click({ force: true });
    cy.get("body").type("{ctrl}D").wait(100);
cy.get('[data-id="abcd"]').click({ force: true });
    cy.get("body").type("{ctrl}Z").wait(100);
```